# I want to know why the size of dist folder is more then src in angular?

Tags: angular, deployment

deploying angular app noticed that size of src folder is 1.38 MB but dist folder size is 20.56 MB.

Comment: All the libraries from node_modules that you're using: their code needs to be deployed too. They're not free. Not to mention that the CLI generates two versions (es5 and es2015) of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its gets the necessary parts from the `node_module packages` and inserts into your code parts, and then removes the rest packages.

So you must not compare `src` and `dist`, but `src + node_modules` with `dist` and you will actually see how `dist` is less that `src + node_modules` :).

Answer (score 0):

You analyse it yourself with tools like webpack analyser

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer